# ios how to remove black border when i taking screenshot (objective c)?

Tags: ios, objective-c

[image]

[image]

I don't want black border when i take screenshot, which is on my output as image. I use this code for output image (XCode 6.2 objective c)
Code :

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.outputView.bounds.size);
    [self.outputView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *sourceImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
     UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.outputView.bounds.size, self.outputView.opaque,0.0);
    [sourceImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0,0)];
    UIImage *croppedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(croppedImage,nil, nil, nil);
    NSData *pngData2 = UIImagePNGRepresentation(croppedImage);
    NSArray *paths2 = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsPath2 = [paths2 objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath2 = [documentsPath2 stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"screen.png"];
    [pngData2 writeToFile:filePath2 atomically:YES];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this code.

**For Swift**

```
func takeScreenShot() -> UIImage
{
      UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, false, 0);
      self.view.drawHierarchy(in: view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
      let image: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
      UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
      return image
}
```

**For Objective C**

```
- (UIImage *)takeScreenShot
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, NO, 2.0f);
    [self.view drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.view.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return image;
}
```

Its work for me.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is create separate or duplicate UIView with actual size and minus double the pixels of border width and replicate the view process and take the screen shot of duplicated view.

Use the following code to take screenshot.

```
- (UIImage *)takeSnapshotOfHighlightingView:(UIView *)originalView {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(originalView.bounds.size, NO, 0);
    [originalView drawViewHierarchyInRect:originalView.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
    UIImage *screenShot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return screenShot;
}
```